# exclude IP from nginx access log

Tags: nginx, logging, configuration, ip

How to exclude some IP address from access log? This is my config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
[...]
access_log /var/www/web/log/access.log;
error_log /var/www/web/log/error.log;

location / { 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
if ($remote_addr = "80.80.80.80") { 
access_log off;
}

location ~ \.php$ { 
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; 
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
} 
[...] 
}
```

And I tried this:

```
map $remote_addr $log_ip { 
"80.80.80.80" 0; 
default 1; 
} 
server { 
[...]
access_log /var/www/web/access.log main if=$log_ip; 
[...]
}
```

Both isn't working. My distribution is Debian 8 and nginx version is 1.9.10 instaled from backport repository.

Thanks o lot for advice

Comment: I have tested your second solution (using map) and I cannot get it to fail. Test your config for syntax errors (`nginx -t`). You can also use `geo` instead of `map` but both seem to work fine for me.

Comment: Second solutions already working. I don't have defined log_format.

Comment: How to make it works with subnet (CIDR).

Answer (score 0):

The second solution works. You could try to check any syntax error by `nginx -t` or upgrade the latest nginx version.